# How to validate Route Parameters in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

As you know Laravel 5 changes the way you call the `validator`, the old way is calling the `validator facade`, but now there is the `ValidatesRequests` trait in base Controller class, but the `validate` method accepts the request as the values array, but when you define your route parameters, these values are not stored in `Request`, so how can I validate those parameters ?

Edit:

Route:

```
Route::get('/react-api/{username}', 'ProfileController@getUsername');
```

Controller:

```
public function getUsername(Request $request, $username)
{
     $v = $this->validate($request, ['username' => 'required']);
}
```

So, the question how can i validate this username parameter ?

Comment: can you emulate what you want to obtain? surely we can make it work if you provide a better description

Comment: I just edited the question, I hope i make it clear now!

Comment: Oh, I see, let me edit my answer

Comment: L5 automatically validate the parameter , Just Type hint it like (User $user)

Answer (score 48):

If you plan to do this directly in your controller method you can do something like:

```
    public function getUser(Request $request)
    {
        $request->merge(['id' => $request->route('id')]);
        $request->validate([
            'id' => [
                'required',
                'exists:users,id'
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

To do this in a custom `FormRequest` class, add the following:

```
    protected function prepareForValidation() 
    {
        $this->merge(['id' => $this->route('id')]);
    }
```

And in your `rules` method:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'id' => [
                'required',
                'exists:users,id'
            ]
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Great idea. With Laravel 8 we can use `$request->route()->parameter('id')` when merging.

Comment: a relevant useful link that worked for me https://dev.to/arielmejiadev/prepareforvalidation-method-in-laravel-form-requests-29ao

Answer (score 10):

Manix's answer wasn't working for me, I was having the same issues as Iliyass. The issue is route parameters aren't automatically available to the FormRequest. I ended up overriding the all() function in my particular FormRequest Class:

```
public function all()
{
    // Include the next line if you need form data, too.
    $request = Input::all();
    $request['username'] = $this->route('username');
    return $request
}
```

Then you can code rules as normal:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'username' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Supposue the following route:

```
Route::get('profile/{id}', 'ProfileController@show');
```

You can still validate `id` parameter as L4 way:

```
public function show(){
    $validator = \Validator::make(
        \Input::all(),
        [
             'id' => ['required', 'numeric']
        ]
    );

    // run validator here
}
```

If you need to validate concrete data, take a look the following example:

```
public function getUsername(Request $request, $username)
{
    $validator = \Validator::make(
        [
             'username' => $username
        ],
        [
             'username' => ['required']
        ]
    );

    // run the validator here
}
```

L5 let you do in two other ways. The first one, using a generic `Request` class injected in the controller:

```
public function show(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'id' => ['required', 'numeric']
    ]);

    // do stuff here, everything was ok
}
```

> In L5 you are allowed to call **validate()** functions that receive the request and the rules to run over it. This functions is in charge of run rules, if some rule fails, then the user is redirected to previous request

Finally, as second option, you can use [Form request validation](http://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation). Remember, every GET and POST value can be accessed via Request class

Comment: Even if i do this validation always fails, when i debug the validate method i found out that $request->all() returns empty array ? i trigger this route within an ajax request.

Comment: Use Input::all() instead, for debugging purposes

Comment: the same as $request->all() return empty array, but when i specify a second argument in the controller action, as $username i got the value that sent !

Comment: This have no sense. Try doing a validator in other controller or something like that

Comment: I end up using the validator facade and validate the old way ! Thanks @manix !

Comment: Will this work with FormRequest since I prefer to use FormRequest rather than Validate

Answer (score 4):

```
public function listTurns($doctor_id, $limit, $offset)
{
    $r = [
        'doctor_id' => $doctor_id,
        'limit' => $limit,
        'offset' => $offset,
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($r, [
        'doctor_id' => 'required|numeric|min:1|exists:doctors,id',
        'limit' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
        'offset' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Validator;

public function getUsername($username)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(['username' => $username], [
      'username' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
      return response()->json(['success' => false, 'errors' => $validator->messages()], 422);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a FormRequest you can merge the value from the URL into the input data by adding a prepareForValidation method to your class.

```
/**
 * Prepare the data for validation.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    // Add the url parameter id into the validation data
    // from a route such as /posts/{id}

    $this->mergeIfMissing(['id' => $this->id]); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

public function getUsername($username) {
    $validator = Validator::make(['username' => $username], [
      'username' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
      return response()->json(['status' => 'error'], 400);
    }
}
```