# Laravel 5 how to validate route parameters?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I want to validate the route parameters in the "form request" but don't know how to do it.

Below is the code sample, I am trying with:

**Route**

```php
// controller Server
Route::group(['prefix' => 'server'], function(){
    Route::get('checkToken/{token}',['as'=>'checkKey','uses'=> 'ServerController@checkToken']);
});
```

**Controller**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;


class ServerController extends Controller {
    public function checkToken( \App\Http\Requests\CheckTokenServerRequest $request) // OT: - why I have to set full path to work??
        {   
            $token = Token::where('token', '=', $request->token)->first();      
            $dt = new DateTime; 
            $token->executed_at = $dt->format('m-d-y H:i:s');
            $token->save();

            return response()->json(json_decode($token->json),200);
        }
}
```

**CheckTokenServerRequest**

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class CheckTokenServerRequest extends Request {

        //autorization

        /**
         * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function rules()
        {

            return [
                'token' => ['required','exists:Tokens,token,executed_at,null']
            ];
        }

}
```

But when I try to validate a simple url http://myurl/server/checkToken/222, I am getting the response:  `no " token " parameter set`.

Is it possible to validate the parameters in a separate "Form request", Or I have to do all in a controller?

ps. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I have already see this: [how-to-validate-route-parameters-in-laravel-5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578153/how-to-validate-route-parameters-in-laravel-5)

Comment: Do you need to validate only route parameters or "mixed" with request parameters?

Comment: Only route parameters.. There are some difference? Thanks!

Comment: have you try using middleware. you even can include more that one middleware. so you can use in group routings. please refer here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware

Comment: Nice question, I like this thread.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**For Laravel < 5.5:**
The way for this is overriding `all()` method for `CheckTokenServerRequest` like so:

```
public function all() 
{
   $data = parent::all();
   $data['token'] = $this->route('token');
   return $data;
}
```

**EDIT**
**For Laravel >= 5.5:**
Above solution works in **Laravel < 5.5**. If you want to use it in **Laravel 5.5 or above**, you should use:

```
public function all($keys = null) 
{
   $data = parent::all($keys);
   $data['token'] = $this->route('token');
   return $data;
}
```

instead.

Comment: I agree that this is the only one solution for this problem, if You want to stick to validation inside request class. Small improvement would be to replace all route parameters automatically: http://pastebin.com/pjwrPme6.

Comment: It works on 5.5/5.5 if you add the `$all = null` parameter to the function.

Comment: I can't use your solution. I have a question about your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52402139/how-to-override-all-method-in-request-validation-class

Answer (score 18):

**Override the `all()` function on the Request object to automatically apply validation rules to the URL parameters**

```
class SetEmailRequest
{

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email'    => 'required|email|max:40',
            'id'       => 'required|integer', // << url parameter
        ];
    }

    public function all()
    {
        $data = parent::all();
        $data['id'] = $this->route('id');

        return $data;
    }

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Access the data normally from the controller like this, after injecting the request:**

```
$setEmailRequest->email // request data
$setEmailRequest->id, // url data
```

Answer (score 11):

If you dont want to specify each route param and just put all route params you can override like this:

**Laravel < 5.5**:

```php
public function all()
{
   return array_merge(parent::all(), $this->route()->parameters());
}
```

**Laravel 5.5 or above**:

```php
public function all($keys = null)
{
   // Add route parameters to validation data
   return array_merge(parent::all(), $this->route()->parameters());
}
```

Comment: If you're using `FormRequest` you can also override the `validationData` method like `protected function validationData() { return $this->route()->parameters() + $this->all(); }`.

Comment: For L8 I use your shorted version $validator = Validator::make(array_merge($request->all(), $request->route()->parameters()), ['country' => 'required...

Answer (score 5):

The form request validators are used for validating **HTML form data** that are sent to server via **POST** method. It is better that you do not use them for validating route parameters. route parameters are mostly used for retrieving data from data base so in order to ensure that your token route parameter is correct change this line of your code, from

```
$token = Token::where('token', '=', $request->token)->first();
```

to

```
$token = Token::where('token', '=', $request->input(token))->firstOrFail();
```

firstOrFail() is a very good function, it sends 404 to your user, if the user insert any invalid token.

you get `no " token " parameter set` because Laravel assumes that your "token" parameter is a POST data which in your case it is not.

if you insist on validating your "token" parameter, by form request validators you gonna slow down your application, because you perform **two** queries to your db, 
one in here

```
$token = Token::where('token', '=', $request->token)->first();
```

and one in here

```
return [
            'token' => ['required','exists:Tokens,token,executed_at,null']
        ];
```

I suggest to use **firsOrFail** to do both **validating** and **retrieving** at once.

Comment: I like your concern and I do agree that parameters validation is not a real responsibility of a `FormRequest` but isn't that so much useful? There's nothing saying at Laravel docs that FormRequests should just be used for `POST` requests. I mean, we have `DELETE`, `PUT` and other types of request that need data validation. If a FormRequest is the way to separate Controller logic from Validation logic, that's the way to go. What do you think about it? I think I changed my mind from this point of view.

Answer (score 3):

A trait can cause this validation to be relatively automagic.

Trait

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

/**
 * Class RouteParameterValidation
 * @package App\Http\Requests
 */
trait RouteParameterValidation{

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $captured_route_vars = false;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function all(){
        return $this->capture_route_vars(parent::all());
    }

    /**
     * @param $inputs
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function capture_route_vars($inputs){
        if($this->captured_route_vars){
            return $inputs;
        }

        $inputs += $this->route()->parameters();
        $inputs = self::numbers($inputs);

        $this->replace($inputs);
        $this->captured_route_vars = true;

        return $inputs;
    }

    /**
     * @param $inputs
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    private static function numbers($inputs){
        foreach($inputs as $k => $input){
            if(is_numeric($input) and !is_infinite($inputs[$k] * 1)){
                $inputs[$k] *= 1;
            }
        }

        return $inputs;
    }

}
```

Usage

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MyCustomRequest extends FormRequest{
    use RouteParameterValidation;

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize(){
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules(){
        return [
            //
            'any_route_param' => 'required'//any rule(s) or custom rule(s)
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I don't think anybody should extend FormRequest for that, it won't be a real form request, if you know what I mean. The trait idea is still great, though..

Comment: @giovannipds - how would you recommend applying the trait?  Extend something else, or make request class from scratch?

Comment: I didn't think about it, perhaps just extending the basic `Request` is the way to go, not the trait. Just not mixing it with `FormRequest`. Of course you can base your code at `FormRequest` but should not extend it from there. As I said, they're things for different concerns. If sometime later `FormRequest` change for any reason, it won't impact on your own `Request`. And of course, that's just my opinion.

Comment: In most cases it should be fine to use the trait on whatever class is spit out by `php artisan make:request ...`

Comment: Yeah... I still thinking about this damn thing. I hate the idea of extending the original `FormRequest` but it's just too damn useful. What does your trait differs from just overriding the `validationData` method like this: `protected function validationData()
    {
        return $this->route()->parameters() + $this->all();
    }`?

Answer (score 1):

For `\App\Http\Requests\CheckTokenServerRequest` you can add `use App\Http\Requests\CheckTokenServerRequest;` at the top.
If you pass the `token` by `url` you can use it likes a variable in `controller`.

```
public function checkToken($token) //same with the name in url
{

    $_token = Token::where('token', '=', $token)->first();      
    $dt = new DateTime; 
    $_token->executed_at = $dt->format('m-d-y H:i:s');
    $_token->save();

    return response()->json(json_decode($token->json),200);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$request->merge(['id' => $id]);
...
$this->validate($request, $rules);
```

or

```
$request->merge(['param' => $this->route('param')]);
...
$this->validate($request, $rules);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just missing the underscore before token. Replace with

> _token

wherever you check it against the form generated by laravel.

```
public function rules()
{

    return [
        '_token' => ['required','exists:Tokens,token,executed_at,null']
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

FormRequest has a method `validationData()` that defines what data to use for validation. So just override that one with route parameters in your form request class:

```
    /**
     * Use route parameters for validation
     * @return array
     */
    protected function validationData()
    {
        return $this->route()->parameters();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

or leave most of the `all` logic in place and override `input` method from `trait \Illuminate\Http\Concerns\InteractsWithInput`

```
     /**
     * Retrieve an input item from the request.
     *
     * @param string|null $key
     * @param string|array|null $default
     * @return string|array|null
     */
    public function input($key = null, $default = null)
    {
        return data_get(
            $this->getInputSource()->all() + $this->query->all() + $this->route()->parameters(), $key, $default
        );
    }
```