# Laravel 5.7 - Override all() method in Request validation Class to validate route parameters?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-request, laravel-5.7

I want to validate the route parameters in the Request validation class. I know this question has been asked many times before but [According to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238285/laravel-5-how-to-validate-route-parameters) I override `all()` method and I receive this error:

```
Class App\Http\Requests\DestroyUserRequest does not exist
```

I'm using Laravel 5.7.

**Route:**

```
Route::delete('/user/{userId}/delete', 'UserController@destroy')->name('user.destroy');
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\DestroyUserRequest;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy(DestroyUserRequest $request)
    {
        User::find($request->route('userId'))->delete();
        return $request->route('userId');
    }
}
```

**DestroyUserRequest:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class DestroyUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'userId' => 'integer|exists:users,id'
        ];
    }

    public function all()
    {
        $data = parent::all();
        $data['userId'] =  $this->route('userId');
        return $data;
    }
}
```

What is wrong to override all() method?

Comment: Apparently autoloader cannot find this class. Did you put it in the correct folder `app/Http/Requests`? Did you try running `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Yes, I put the file in the correct folder. When I remove all() method from DestroyUserRequest class, the error will be solved! I'm really confused!

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I run `composer dump-autoload` but problem not solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error your get seems to be quite strange. I believe the problem is here because your method signature is not the same as parent.

It should be:

```
public function all($keys = null)
{
    $data = parent::all($keys);
    $data['userId'] =  $this->route('userId');
    return $data;
}
```

because signature of `Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php` is:

```
/**
 * Get all of the input and files for the request.
 *
 * @param  array|mixed  $keys
 * @return array
 */
public function all($keys = null)
```

The change was made in Laravel 5.5. You can read in [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade#upgrade-5.5.0):

> The all Method
>
> If you are overriding the all method of the Illuminate\Http\Request
>   class, you should update your method signature to reflect the new
>   $keys argument:
>
> public function all($keys =  null) {

Answer (score 0):

### Laravel 8+

```php
    /**
     * Get all of the models from the database.
     *
     * @param  array|mixed  $columns
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
     */
    public static function all($columns = ['*'])
    {
        $data = parent::all($columns);
        $data['userId'] =  $this->route('userId');
        return $data;
    }
```