# Laravel 7.4 - Outside of regular expressions, is there any way to validate the parameters of the URL string in a GET request?

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I have a URL of the following form:

```
GET /cat/{cat}/meows/{overTime}
```

I can write a controller method that looks like this in order to capture the values:

```
public function getMeowsOverTime(Cat cat, int overTime)
```

What I would like is to validate the `{cat}` and `{overTime}` values before it gets to the controller method.

I have tried creating a custom `MeowsOverTimeRequest` object that extends `Illuminate\Http\Request` according to the recommendation here: [Laravel 5.7 - Override all() method in Request validation Class to validate route parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52402139/laravel-5-7-override-all-method-in-request-validation-class-to-validate-rout)

So that would be:

```
class MeowsOverTimeRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function all($keys = null)
    {
        $request = parent::all($keys);
        $request['cat'] = $this->route('cat');
        $request['overTime'] = $this->route('overTime');
        return $request;
    }

    /**
    * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'cat' =>
            [
                'required',
                'integer'
            ],
            'overTime' =>
            [
                'required',
                'integer',
                Rule::in(Cat::getMeowTimeOptions())
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

But `$this->route('cat')` and `$this->route('overTime')` both return null. How can I access these variables?

I would prefer not to use [regular expression validation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) due to the `overTime` being limited by what is returned from `Cat::getMeowTimeOptions`