# Laravel - Is it possible to validate a get wildcard Request with Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have a GET route with a wildcard **day**.

This day wildcard is a string like so: 20220507 (YYYYMMDD).

After validation the string I wish to make a proper response. Before sending the response I want to validate the string length and the format.

My question is, is it possible to validate the string with **Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest** ou **Illuminate\Http\Request**
*make:request* ? Or they only accepet Post Requests ?

Code:

```
php artisan make:request CalendarDayRequest
```

Example get route in web.php

```
Route::get('/calendar/{day}' , 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@calendar')->name('calendar');
```

Example Controller

```
use App\Http\Requests\CalendarDayRequest; 
public function calendar ( CalendarDayRequest $request ) {
    // Code
}
```

Or Example Controller 2

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function calendar ( Request $request ) {
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'day' => 'required',
     ]);
}
```

Both of them I got the error:  infinite redirect loop, redirected it too many times.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can not validate route parameters inside Form Request

But, you can use regex for validating your route
Example:

```php
Route::get('/calendar/{day}', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@calendar')
    ->name('calendar')
    ->where('day', '/^[0-9]{4}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/');
```

If You still want to use `validate()` function or Form Request

```php
$request->merge([
   'day' => $day
]);

$this->validate($request, [
   'day' => 'date_format:Ymd',
]);
```

Form Request Way - Override `all()` method

```
public function all($k = null){
   $data = parent::all($k);
   $data['day'] = $this->route('day');
   return $data;
}
```

If Nothing Works, Try Following code

```
public function calendar(Request $request, $day){
 $data = $request->all();
 $data['day'] = $day; 

 $validator = Validator::make($data, [
   'day' => 'required|date_format:Ymd',
 ]);
  
 if($validator->fails()){
    // Do Something abort(404);
 }

}
```

[Laravel 5 how to validate route parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238285/laravel-5-how-to-validate-route-parameters)

But I would suggest you to send it as request parameter if you want to use `validate()` function.

Comment: For some reason the ```->where('day', '/^[0-9]{4}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/');``` is not working, giving me 404 .

Comment: The same problem happens with the validation fails with ```Form Request Way - Override all() method``` , infinity loop :  too many redirects

Comment: in  `public function calendar ( Request $request, $day ) {
    $request->merge(['day'  => $day  ]);  $request->validate([ 'day' => 'date_format:Ymd', ]);
}`

Comment: If Merge does'nt work try `$request->request->add(['day', $day]);`

Answer (score 0):

In Example 1:

You should overwrite this method in CalendarDayRequest:

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {
    throw (new ValidationException($validator))
                ->errorBag($this->errorBag)
                ->redirectTo($this->getRedirectUrl());
}
```

If client expects json, laravel will return a json field instead of redirection. You can completely change this behavior by changing this method or customizing render() method in App\Exceptions\Handler.

In Example 2:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

public function calendar ( Request $request ) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), ['day'=>'required']);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        $messages = $validator->errors()->messages();
        $messageBag = $validator->errors()->getMessageBag();
    };
}
```

So you can use messages of validator for informing client.